# Get photos of Test User using Facebook API in javascript

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook API and I create a test user under `Roles->TestUsers` with the premission of `publish_actios, user_photos` When I login using this user and try to get photos or feeds it return empty response.
Here is my javascript code.

```
        FB.api('me/feed', function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
```

This return response like this `Object {data: Array[0]}` I try it with photos same result. But when I try only `FB.api('me',function...` it's working fine return name and id of this user but why this is not working for `photos and feeds`. I upload some photos using this test user on facebook account.
Sorry, I'm new in this and have not much knowledge about this.

**UPDATE**

I debug the accessToken get these results.

```
Application ID  1017793531681977 : codeDeveloper
User ID 104922836661684
Issued  Unknown
Expires 1479805200 (in about an hour)
Valid   True
Origin  Unknown
Scopes  user_photos, user_friends, email, publish_actions, public_profile
```

I also add three photos in test user account.I'm using this javascript code.

```
 FB.api('me/photos',...
```

It return response `Object {data: Array[0]}`  why this is not getting any results. This is a test user and I didn't apply for any review permission.
Because first I need any test user from where I can test my app and submit for
reviews how can i do that.

**UPDATE**

```
     function statusChangeCallback(response) {
        if (response.status === 'connected') {
            testAPI();
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {

        } else {

        }
    }

    function checkLoginState() {
        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });
    }

    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
            appId      : '101**********77',  
            cookie     : true,  // enable cookies to allow the server to access
                                // the session
            xfbml      : true,  // parse social plugins on this page
            version    : 'v2.8' // use graph api version 2.5
        });

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
            statusChangeCallback(response);
        });

    };

    (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

    function testAPI() {
        FB.api('me/photos', function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }
```

In HTML Body

```
  <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,user_photos,publish_actions" onlogin="checkLoginState();">
```

Answer (score 0):

`publish_actions` is for posting, for reading the feed you need the `user_posts` permission.

`user_photos` is correct for getting the photos, the endpoint is `/me/photos`.

Debug the Token and make sure it includes the correct permissions: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/

Comment: I tried it with `/me/photos` but this is also not working. Same result `Object {data: Array[0]}`

Comment: then there are either no photos or you did not authorize with user_photos correctly. did you try with your own account too? did you debug the access token to make sure it includes the permissions you need?

Comment: again, did you try with your own user instead of the test user? there may be a bug, who knows.

Comment: I try it with my own user when I try to login with original account it show a notice that some permission need approval submit for review something like that. I continue this one but same result not record found.

Comment: it is just a warning that you need to go through review if you want to put your app live for other users. anyway, did you try it in the api explorer too? > https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=me%2Fphotos&version=v2.8

Comment: did you seriously just post your facebook credentials?

Comment: i will definitely not login with another facebook account. that´s crazy, you should delete the password asap. we are developers here, we do stuff the right way.

Comment: but I'm not able to get any solution of this. Without this I'm not able to get facebook premissions. Please let me know a time that suite you best and I will make sure that I make myself available.

Comment: if you have photos on your account, and you are 100% sure the access token includes the user_photos permission, you may just file a bug.

Comment: I think problem is that those permissions that are not approved by facebook like `user_photos,publish_actions,user_friends etc` return back this result `Object {data: Array[0]}`. But I think for test user there is no need to approval these permission.

Comment: I tried it using `Grap API explore` here it is working fine.Is there any problem in code, I update the question please check it

Comment: I also post a question on facebook community forum but no reply. https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=120896378394419&added&rdrhc&__mref=message_bubble

Comment: this will usually only happen if the access token does not include the user_photos permission. you don´t need review for testing, just use a user with a role int he app.